# How to animate a line in android?

Tags: android

I need to draw a line from point A(x1,y1) to point B(x2, y2). But instead of just show the line, I need to see the line was actually drawn - little bit by little bit, at a controllable speed - from point A to point B. I've tried alarms and loops for this but cant find my solution.I am working on surface view. Please give solution for this

Comment: in a loop, draw the line bigger and bigger until it fills the entire desired length. aka, a line from A, part way to B. then further to B, etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U can do it like this:

```
    private int startX = 0;
    private int startY = 0;

    private int endX = 0;
    private int endY = 0;

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);

        if (endX != 300 && endY != 300) { // set end points
            endY++;
            endX++;

            postInvalidateDelayed(15); // set time here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ca you please explain that how postInvalidateDelayed(delay); works?

Comment: Yes. Methods invalidate() and postInvalidate() call draw() method to readraw the view immediately. So postInvalidateDelayed(delay) work with delay, so this looks like animation.

Comment: I think it would be good to use `postInvalidateDelayed(1000 / 30);` or 1000/60 to get 30 or 60 fps or some other value