# Draw a line on canvas slowly like an animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I need to draw a line between two points. In the display, it shows like a pen is drawing the line. But how can I make the line appear only after pen passes? I tried this

```
var x= 10
var y=10

var h=Handler()
h.postDelayed({
    While(true)
    {
        x++
        y++
        if(x<=100&&y<=100){
            canvas.drawLine(10,10,x,y,paint)
        }
        else break
    }
}, 100 )
```

But this code is making the canvas look weird and some random lines are appearing.

Any better way to do this?

Edit:

I tried  the method given in link below

https://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/how-to-animate-line-gradually-growing-from-starting-point-to-ending-point/

I am a beginner . how can i use  different positions for each case... 
 Also how can we call a class with context?. I tried `getApplicationContext()` but giving NPE.  The same code works perfectly in `onCreate()`. But i need to call it outside that.

I am hoping for a good help

Comment: A better way is to use "Linear Interpolation". That way you avoid stuttering / scrambling by differences within the timer.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/29446690/4146722

Comment: Can you give an example program of linear interpolation? I need the line to appear on different co ordinates. For single co ordinate we can use the xml